# CSS Position Problems in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I am by no means a web developer, I am more on the infrastructure side of things.  Anyway, I built a FreeBSD server with an AMP stack on an XServe G4 and wanted to spruce up the generic landing page that only printed "It Works!" on a plain white screen to something a bit more interesting when I ran into a an issue with CSS.

Here's the page - it works exactly the way it's supposed to on Chrome, Opera, Safari on both Mac and Win10 (I didn't check Safari on Win10)

[image: Landing Page]

On Microsoft Edge, I get this:

[image: Landing Page on Edge]

### What do I need to do in my CSS so that I can correctly position that element?

The code for the page is below

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
           background-image: url("splash.png");
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-position: center;
           background-color: #BEBEBE;
           font-family: "Arial", "Verdana", "serif";
           justify-content: center;
       }

  #container { display: block; position: relative;
               width: 60%; 
               top: 60%;   
               font-weight: bold;
               margin: auto;
       }



   #pretext { display: inline-block; color: #b80000; font-size: 3em;
            }
   #posttext { display: inline-block;
               color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 3.5em;
               font-weight: 1500; }

   #logo   {
             height: 50px; 
             position: absolute; 
             bottom: 1%;
             right:  1%;
             padding-bottom: 5px; 

           }
   #logo img   { height: inherit; vertical-align: top; }

   #svr-info { font-size: .75em; 
               color: #dae6f7;
               width: auto;
               position: absolute;
               bottom: 0px;
               right: 10px;
               padding-top: 5px;

             }

    #phpinfo a  {  font-size:  .75em;
                   text-decoration: none;
                }

     a:hover { font-size:  1.3em; }


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="pretext">Think</div>
  <div id="posttext">Correctly.</div>
</div>
<div id="logo">
  <img src="powerpc-logo.png" />
  <img src="apple-logo.png" />
</div> <br>

<div id="svr-info">
<?php 
    echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
    echo "---";
    echo php_uname('r');
    echo "  ";
    echo php_uname('m');

?>
</div>
<div id="phpinfo">
<a href="test.php"> PHPINFO Page</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't repro the issue for me: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/zmrbukr3/

Comment: Using your link, Chrome shows it at the top no matter what % I give it.  However, according to W3shools.com, this should work:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_top_percent&preval=10%25

Comment: you can read this about display: table http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/277778/why-are-people-making-tables-with-divs

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .container {
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .text1 {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" >
    <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 30%;">
        <img src="logo.png" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"/>
        <br/>
        <h1 class="text1">Think Correctly</h1>
    </div>

    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px;">
        <img src="logo2.png"/><span>Logo 2</span>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

try to make it using this code
you can read this about using tables vs using divs with display table
[divs vs tables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277778/why-are-people-making-tables-with-divs)

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, I should put what I had in the `container` div into a table?  I put that text into a div so I could move it anywhere on the page.

Comment: this is one way to do it, but you can do it using other methods.

Comment: Please if this solved your problem mark it as answered :)

Comment: Like I said, I am not a web developer, but what I do know is that using tables for layout has been deprecated.  The proper way of laying out elements is through CSS; which is what I am attempting to do.  As for the counting related elements together, I don't see how having them defined in the `<head>` section takes away from any of the performance or functionality of the page.  I write a lot in BASH but trained in C and Java; this style makes sense to me.

Comment: I am not using a table its a div with display property set to table. 
that's a whole different but if you hate display table remove it and set div width to a percent or to specified pixels. 
the one that deprecated is the <table> tag.

Comment: also I am doing everything using css style but these called inline styles.
I did that for the sake of speed. in your project you need to cut and paste them inside <style> tag. read about inline styles.

Comment: @TawfiqabuHalawah and all junior developers and web designers: just want to say that the `<table>` tag IS NOT deprecated at all. It still part of the HTML spec in all its glory. What is NOT used for anymore (hence you could say that method IS "deprecated"), is for layout. Read more about the `<table>` tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```
#container { 
  top: 60%;
}
```

what do you mean by 60%;
60% of what?!

if you want to container be in center you can use **top: 60vh** (if you want 60% of viewport height)

but its better to put both #logo and #container into a div and set its position.